Please identify the movie: Joker looking guy with a gang of boys, ends up in psychological treatement against Cynical activities
Hero is leader of a gang that does lots of public destruction and gets psychological treatment not to do such activities.. later he goes into hands of the guy whose daughter was raped and killed by hero's gang. Psycho movie.
Hero has this stick that he swings all the time.

This sounds to a large degree like Stanley Kubrick's A Clockwork Orange:

Protagonist Alex is an "ultraviolent" youth in futuristic Britain. As
  with all luck, his eventually runs out and he's arrested and convicted
  of murder and rape. While in prison, Alex learns of an experimental
  program in which convicts are programed to detest violence. If he goes
  through the program his sentence will be reduced and he will be back
  on the streets sooner than expected. But Alex's ordeals are far from
  over once he hits the mean streets of Britain that he had a hand in
  creating.


@user10766 What? So you knew it already? Identify questions are not really made to play a little game of quiz.

No! i forgot the name and google was not helping. You did.

@user10766 Ah, Ok then.

Appreciate your selfless help. I am searching some Cynicism based movies.

@JerinAntony Haha, in a points-driven system my actions are surely not selfless. ;-) "I am searching some Cynicism based movies." - Not sure what you mean with that.

:D Yeah.. there is no selfless act. Cynicism is violation of generally agreed norms of life.. Fight Club like movies.. (not a perfect example)

@JerinAntony Not sure I would define cynicism this way, but in either interpretation I cannot come up with any movie recommendations as that's quite broad. But feel free to ask any recommendation questions in [chat] (as you probably know, neither questions nor comments fit that well) and maybe someone has some ideas.
